# ACF and Gravity Forms Plugin Integration (Using a for loop)

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm using [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) for Wordpress in combination with a [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-gravityforms-add-on/) that integrates Gravity Forms.

The plugin makes available a `gravity_forms` function in which to display a specific gravity form to the frontend.

As per the plugin's [documentation](https://github.com/DannyvanHolten/acf-gravityforms-add-on), I am using a for loop to loop through all gravity forms and display the form selected in the backend on the page.

My code looks as follows:

```
if( have_rows('content_area') ):
while ( have_rows('content_area') ) : the_row(); 
    if( get_row_layout() == 'gravity_form' ):
        $form = get_sub_field('form'); 
            foreach($forms as $form) {
                gravity_form($form, true, true, false, '', true, 1); 
    }
    endif;
endwhile;
else :
// do nothing
endif;
```

When I remove the foreach loop and pass a specific form ID into the `gravity_form` function (instead of the `$form` variable) it outputs the correct form to the page.

My PHP skills aren't that great so I suspect it is something I am missing that the documentation hasn't included.

Here are some screenshots of my ACF setup.

[image]

[image]

it may, or may not be worth noting that I also tried with:

`$form = get_field('form');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the foreach because the var $forms do not exists, so it can't works.

Try instead :

```
if( have_rows('content_area') ):
while ( have_rows('content_area') ) : the_row(); 
    if( get_row_layout() == 'gravity_form' ):
       if( get_row_layout() == 'gravity_form' ):
           gravity_form(get_sub_field('form'), true, true, false, '', true, 1); 
       }
    }
    endif;
endwhile;
else :
// do nothing
endif;
```

**EDIT:**
If you are returning more than one form, you can use the foreach but with the right variable so juste replace `$form = get_sub_field('form');` by `$forms = get_sub_field('form')`